# In what way was Joseph Conrad influenced by Antoni Malczewski?

Tags: inspiration, joseph-conrad, antoni-malczewski

[Antoni Malczewski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antoni_Malczewski) was a Polish romantic poet, known for his only work, “a narrative poem of dire pessimism, Maria (1825). Wikipedia writes

> *Maria* was also influential on later Polish poets, especially Adam Mickiewicz, and on writer Joseph Conrad.

As Conrad was not a romantic writer I’m unable to digest that Antoni Malczewski’s work influenced him.